# In PHP how do you format a number as currency handling cases such as 10 cents equaling "$.1";

Tags: php, formatting, currency

I currently do:

```
 $totalBill = number_format($totalBill, 2); 
 $totalBill = '$'.$totalBill;
```

This does not handle cases though where the total is say 10 cents. It returns "$0.1" which I do not want. Does anyone have a better way?

Comment: That code works fine for me when `$totalBill` is `0.1`.

Comment: What I mean is it doesn't include the trailing 0 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$totalBill = sprintf('$%.2f',$totalBill);
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want [`money_format()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) instead

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's [money_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) function.